# 80's-90's short story: nothing rhymes with orange

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, androids

Growing up in the 80's and 90's, I read a sci-fi short story once about the human race being threatened by androids.

The character in the story was talking to his friend about the androids, discussing possible ways to defeat them.  The boy says that when the androids encounter a problem they can't solve it blows their circuits, and suggested as an example the problem of finding a word that rhymes with "orange."  As it turned out, the friend was an android and the problem blew his circuits.  I have looked but can't find the story.  If anyone here has an idea I'd love to know.

Comment: Hi there, welcome to the site! :) could you take a look at [this guide on how to ask a good story-ID question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028) to see if that triggers any more memories you could [edit] into your answer? For instance, did you read that in a newspaper, a collection of short stories?  If so do you remember what the cover looked like? Things like that, to increase the chance of having a successful identification. Cheers!

Comment: Also, may I say it's _strange_ this android obviously knew nothing of [_lozenge_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lozenge) and [_sporange_](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sporange#English)...

Comment: GLaDOS:  This. Sentence. Is. FALSE.
GLaDOS: Don't think about it, don't think about it!
Wheatley:  Um, true. I'll go with true. There, that was easy. To be honest, I might have heard that one before.

Answer (score 6):

This is "Mission:  Survival" by Curt Fischer, from the August 1988 issue of *Boys' Life*.  It is available at [Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=2WYEAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA26).

When faced with certain kinds of puzzles, the robotoid impostors will burn out their brains, trying to solve them until smoke comes out of their ears.

> "How about a rhyme?" Bobby suggested.
>
> Wheeler and Freiberg smiled.
>
> "No, Bobby," said Wheeler, "a rhyme would be too simple.  A robotoid would come up with countless rhymes for every word that...."

Comment: That's it.  Thank you Buzz!

Comment: @BenThornal I remember this story rather fondly myself.  Could you please accept my answer, but clicking the check mark next to my answer?